# One subject + two different verb with neither nor structure

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I am confused about which one of the following sentences correct are.Is there any other way to say them using this structure also?

> 1.I can neither drink nor eat now.
>
> 2.I can neither drink nor can I eat now.
>
> 3.I can neither drink nor I can eat now.

---

> 4.I cannot drink nor eat now.
>
> 5.I cannot drink nor can I eat now.
>
> 6.I cannot drink nor I can eat now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1 and 4 are normal.

2 and 5 are rather literary or poetic: they are grammatical and clear, but would be used when you want a certain rhythm to the sentence.

3 and 6 are ungrammatical, because clauses headed by *neither* or *nor* exhibit subject-verb inversion.

Answer (score 1):

Examples 1 and 4 are correct.

When you have a neither/nor construction in a sentence, everything that comes before the *neither* will also apply to what comes after the *nor*. In other words, it is redundant to use *can I* in the second part of the sentence, as example 2 does. Furthermore, it's flat-out wrong to use *I can* in that spot, as example 3 does.

Example 4 is correct, though I would say it sounds more natural with the use of *or* instead: "I cannot eat or drink." Example 5 is the same as 2; it's not incorrect, per se, but also not necessary to repeat the first part of the verb phrase. You may find the section titled "When to use either'nor' or 'or'" in Grammar Girl's article [here](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/when-use-nor?page=1) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

'I can neither drink nor eat now' is correct

The following three starting with "I can neither.." are awkwardly worded. 
'I can neither drink nor can I eat now' is grammatically okay, but awkward and wordy.

'I can neither eat nor I can eat now' is just weird. In this situation, nor should be followed by an auxiliary verb such as 'can' or 'will'

All the I *cannot **_ nor _** are double negatives